# Unity3d iOS joystick?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, joystick, gamepad

There is a joystick that connects to Android and iOS devices. On Android it works completely , the unity3d sees it , and work out pressing buttons . And iOS joystick connected , controls the volume and the " home"-button of iPhone, but Unity does not see it .

According to the next, Unity must see it. I have tried all Unity versions.
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-joystick.html

If who faced with a problem , please help!

Answer (score 1):

I found! There is a plugin for Unity.
If it was usefull, vote please!

https://github.com/mattfox12/iCade-Unity

Comment: Its very outdated.